# Why does Neil do this?

Tags: timeline, tenet

After Neil catches up to the masked person in the airport, he stops the protagonist from killing the inverted masked person.

> Later on, it is revealed that at that point Neil knew both the function of the turnstiles and the identity of the masked person (future Protagonist), and had been recruited by an even older Protagonist. But if so, he must have realized the Protagonist had a future and was therefore not killable according to the rule 'What's happened happened'. And even if he had never been recruited by the future Protagonist, the fact that the future Protagonist was inverted and had been fighting moments before would be enough for Neil to realize that the Protagonist could not be killed at that moment, as he was alive in his own future timeline between that moment and the moment he would enter the turnstile. It should be impossible to kill an inverted person who was alive in your past, because that means he is alive in his own future.

Then why did Neil see a need to stop him from killing the masked person?

Comment: Killing your boss is rarely a good idea

Comment: Maybe Neil's intervention _is_ the mechanism that preserves the masked version of Protagonist.  After all, it happened, so that must have been the way it always happened.

Comment: Consider editing your post so that only the most spoilery stuff gets hidden behind a spoiler block. Right now you have a bland title and a question of which 80% is hidden. Don't sugarcoat it for people who haven't seen the movie; their loss if they want to read a question about something they don't want to be spoiled about.